Which metals utensils are used for Naivedya for which deities?
I have where heard that different deities like different metals for the offerings of Naivedya, but not sure of any scriptural reference.
According to what I have heard is

Deities like Sri Hari, and Mata Lakshmi like Gold utensils most, Brass second, Copper third

Whereas Shiva and Durga likes Copper most.

I have seen Tamra and Silver Kosha Kushi in Bengal, can it be also made of Gold, the wealth of Yajaman allows, what is the best for the pleasing of the deity?



There is no such thing.

Apart from gold and silver which most devotees can not use copper and brass are the most common metals used. Some people use even steel made utensils to offer naivedya. Naivedya can also be offered in plates made from banana leaves,stone or even clay.
